# Thinning in Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

please help in providing a proof like explanation. I am confused and do no know where to start.

> Let $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$ be independent Poisson processes with rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Using thinning/superposition, find the probability that the process $(X_t,Y_t)$ ever visits the state $(i,j)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward computation:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X_t=i,Y_t=j)\ \mathsf dt &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X_t=i)\mathbb P(Y_t=j)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^{\infty } e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^i}{i!}e^{-\mu t}\frac{(\mu t)^j}{j!}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \frac{\lambda^i\mu^j}{(\lambda+\mu)^{i+j+1}} \cdot \frac{(i+j+1)!}{i!j!}.
\end{align}